# Добавление элемента в начало списка Python

Tags: python, list

Есть функция **append()**, но она добавляет элемент в конец списка, какую функцию использовать чтобы она добавляла в начало?
Например

```
[10,100,55]
Добавить 5 в начало 
[5,10,100,55]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
l = [10,100,55]
```

Вариант 1:

```
l.insert(0, 5)
```

Вариант 2:

```
l = [5] + l
```

Answer (score 6):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом `insert`, который вставляет элемент в указанную первым аргументом позицию.

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    li = [10, 100, 55]
    li.insert(0, 5)
    print(li)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
[5, 10, 100, 55]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l.insert(0,5)
```

**l.insert** - функция, с помощью которой мы добавляем в самое начало списка 
(0), а потом указываем, что мы хотим добавить,
 в нашем случае - 5.

То есть: l.insert - добавить,
0 - место на которое нужно добавить элемент,
и 5 - то, что нужно добавить.